# Known estimate for gaussian sum $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q} \psi( a x^m + b x^n)$?

Tags: finite-fields, characters

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field, $\psi$ be a non-trivial additive character over $\mathbb{F}_q$, and $a, b \in \mathbb{F}_q$ constants. Is there any known estimate for the gaussian sum

$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q} \psi( a x^m + b x^n),$$

possibly for specific values of $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}$, $m \ne n$?

Comment: For $m = n = 2$ and $q$ odd, it is (what I think of as) a classical Gauss sum, whose value is well known: the square is $q\operatorname{sgn}_{\mathbb F_q}(-(a + b))$, and the sign is known in terms of how $\psi$ differs from the "basic" character $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i\operatorname{tr}_{\mathbb F_q/\mathbb F_p}(x)/p}$.

Comment: Thank you. However, now I realize that I must also assume $m\ne n$, otherwise it would be just a monomial gaussian sum. I will edit the question to add this.

Comment: Weil proved in general that the modulus of $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q} \psi(f(x))$ is at most $(\deg f - 1)\sqrt{q}$ for any polynomial $f$ not of the shape $g^p-g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ofir Gorodetsky notes in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422709/known-estimate-for-gaussian-sum-sum-x-in-mathbbf-q-psi-a-xm-b-xn#comment1086256_422709), Weil's bound gives that the absolute value of the sum is most order $\max(m,n) \sqrt{q}$. This is non-trivial as long as $m$ and $n$ are $o(\sqrt{q})$, after this the estimate is worse than the trivial bound.

When $m$ and $n$ are large there are known estimates from additive combinatorics, at least when $q$ is prime. There are some obstructions to estimates, particularly when $m$, $n$ or $m-n$ have a large common factor with $q-1$. Otherwise one can obtain cancellation. See: J. Bourgain's paper "[Mordell's Exponential Sum Estimate Revisited](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-05-00476-5)".